# How do I apply rounded corners on the bottom of a TableView in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

My app has a page which loads data fetched from async API calls into three tableViews. I set up all the data in `viewDidLoad`.

The table height dynamically changes depending on the number of rows, this is the reason I have the constraint in `viewDidLoad`:

```
func setupTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // People
    self.loadPeople() { (boolValue) -> () in
        self.peopleNumberLabel.text = self.getPeoplesNumberText(self.numberOfPeople)
        self.peopleTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.peopleTableView.contentSize.height
        self.setupTableView(self.peopleTableView)
        self.peopleTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    }
    ... // Two other table views
}
```

I'm trying to set the rounded corners **only on the bottom** of each table like so:

```
func setUpBottomRoundedCorners(view: UIView) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:view.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[UIRectCorner.BottomRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(3, 3))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

But whenever I apply this on the table view with

```
setUpBottomRoundedCorners(self.peopleTableView)
```

It either cuts my tableview off at the original height before the data changes the height, or hides the table completely. I've tried it in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.

I'm obviously missing something, what's wrong?

Comment: Apply rounded corners to the last cell instead of whole tableView.